# Error on AndroidStudio when building app Ionic/Capacitor

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, compiler-errors

i'm developing an app with Ionic & Capacitor for android. When I try to build the project in Android Studio I have this error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method compile() for arguments [me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Searching on internet I should replace 'compile' with implementation to match gradle version, but I haven't any compile in my code nor in the build.gralde.

How can I solve it?